# AttributeError: 'TestCase' object has no attribute 'lineno', when I try to run test with datadriver library

Tags: python, robotframework, data-driven-tests, data-driven

I wanted to do a test with the DataDriver library, but it doesn't seem to work, I have the following error:

```
[ ERROR ] Calling method '_start_suite' of listener 'DataDriver' failed: AttributeError: 'TestCase' object has no attribute 'lineno'
first test case exemple                                               | FAIL |
Test case contains no keywords.
```

This is my test file.robot :

```
*** Settings ***  
Library           OperatingSystem
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           DataDriver   file=../../Resources/data_test.csv
 
Suite Teardown    Close Browser
Test Template     Open web site 

*** Test Cases ***             
first test case exemple        ${URL}    ${Browser}     
    
 
*** Keywords *** 
Open web site
    [Arguments]    ${URL}    ${Browser}    
    Open Browser    ${URL}    ${Browser}
```

My file.csv contains the variable `${URL}` and `${Browser}`

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: What is your Robot Framework version and what is your DataDriver version? Seems like they mismatch.

Comment: DataDriver version is : 1.1.2 and , RobotFramwork (before upgrading into 4.0 ) was 3.1.2 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Robot Framework 4.0 a backward incompatible change has been introduced: [Running and result models have been changed](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-4.0.rst#running-and-result-models-have-been-changed). One part of that change is the following:

In 4.0 the [`robot.running.model.TestCase`](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodoc/robot.running.html#robot.running.model.TestCase) class has [`lineno`](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodoc/robot.running.html#robot.running.model.TestCase.lineno) attribute.
Before 4.0, for example in 3.1.2 the [`robot.running.model.TestCase`](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.1.2/autodoc/robot.running.html#robot.running.model.TestCase) class does not have `lineno` attribute.

Given the DataDriver wants to use `lineno` I would say your framework version is lower than 4.0 and you need to upgrade to the latest release.

Comment: Thank you , it really helped me.
I actually had an earlier version of robotframework 3.1.2, why the problem